# ld: library not found for -|base64

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native and on android it runs correctly but on iOS when I tried to run on Xcode gives me the error: Library not found for -lBase64.

I have thought that perhaps it could be react-native-code-push since this is the library that uses base64 but I have investigated thoroughly and I cannot find any documentation or anything that can provide me with information on how to solve this issue

podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
  - Base64 (1.1.2)
  - boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
  - CodePush (5.7.0):
    - Base64 (~> 1.1)
    - JWT (~> 3.0.0-beta.7)
    - React
    - SSZipArchive (~> 2.1)
  - DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (5.0.2):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (= 5.0.2)
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (= 5.0.2)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (5.0.2)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (5.0.2):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics
  - FBSDKLoginKit (5.0.2):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
  - FBSDKShareKit (5.0.2):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
  - Firebase/AdMob (6.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.44)
  - Firebase/Core (6.3.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.0.2)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.3.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.0.3)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.0.2):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 4.2)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.0.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseCore (6.0.3):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.0)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (4.2.7):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.0)
  - Folly (2018.10.22.00):
    - boost-for-react-native
    - DoubleConversion
    - glog
  - glog (0.3.5)
  - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.67.0):
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (6.0.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - GoogleMaps (3.1.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Maps (= 3.1.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Base (3.1.0)
  - GoogleMaps/Maps (3.1.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base
  - GooglePlaces (3.1.0):
    - GoogleMaps/Base (= 3.1.0)
  - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (1.4.0)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.7.2):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.7.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - IQKeyboardManager (4.0.13)
  - JWT (3.0.0-beta.14):
    - Base64 (~> 1.1.2)
  - nanopb (0.3.9011):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.9011)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.9011)
  - OneSignal (2.10.0)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.12)
  - QBImagePickerController (3.4.0)
  - React (0.59.9):
    - React/Core (= 0.59.9)
  - react-native-camera (2.11.0):
    - React
    - react-native-camera/RCT (= 2.11.0)
    - react-native-camera/RN (= 2.11.0)
  - react-native-camera/RCT (2.11.0):
    - React
  - react-native-camera/RN (2.11.0):
    - React
  - react-native-fbsdk (0.10.0):
    - React
    - react-native-fbsdk/Core (= 0.10.0)
    - react-native-fbsdk/Login (= 0.10.0)
    - react-native-fbsdk/Share (= 0.10.0)
  - react-native-fbsdk/Core (0.10.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0.0)
    - React
  - react-native-fbsdk/Login (0.10.0):
    - FBSDKLoginKit (~> 5.0.0)
    - React
  - react-native-fbsdk/Share (0.10.0):
    - FBSDKShareKit (~> 5.0.0)
    - React
  - react-native-google-places (3.1.1):
    - GoogleMaps (~> 3.1.0)
    - GooglePlaces (~> 3.1.0)
    - React
  - react-native-keep-awake (3.2.0):
    - React
  - react-native-onesignal (3.2.14):
    - OneSignal (= 2.10.0)
    - React
  - react-native-splash-screen (3.2.0):
    - React
  - react-native-video (4.4.2):
    - React
    - react-native-video/Video (= 4.4.2)
  - react-native-video/Video (4.4.2):
    - React
  - React/Core (0.59.9):
    - yoga (= 0.59.9.React)
  - React/CxxBridge (0.59.9):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - React/Core
    - React/cxxreact
    - React/jsiexecutor
  - React/cxxreact (0.59.9):
    - boost-for-react-native (= 1.63.0)
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React/jsinspector
  - React/DevSupport (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTWebSocket
  - React/fishhook (0.59.9)
  - React/jsi (0.59.9):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
  - React/jsiexecutor (0.59.9):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React/cxxreact
    - React/jsi
  - React/jsinspector (0.59.9)
  - React/RCTActionSheet (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTAnimation (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTBlob (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTGeolocation (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTImage (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
    - React/RCTNetwork
  - React/RCTLinkingIOS (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTNetwork (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTPushNotification (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTSettings (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTText (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTVibration (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
  - React/RCTWebSocket (0.59.9):
    - React/Core
    - React/fishhook
    - React/RCTBlob
  - ReactNativeKeyboardManager (4.0.13-12):
    - IQKeyboardManager (= 4.0.13)
    - React
    - React/RCTText
  - ReactNativeLocalization (2.1.2):
    - React
  - RNCAsyncStorage (1.5.0):
    - React
  - RNDeviceInfo (2.1.3):
    - React
  - RNGestureHandler (1.3.0):
    - React
  - RNImageCropPicker (0.24.1):
    - QBImagePickerController
    - React/Core
    - RSKImageCropper
  - RNVectorIcons (6.6.0):
    - React
  - RSKImageCropper (3.0.2)
  - SSZipArchive (2.4.2)
  - yoga (0.59.9.React)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - CodePush (from `../node_modules/react-native-code-push`)
  - DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`)
  - Firebase/AdMob (~> 6.3.0)
  - Firebase/Core (~> 6.3.0)
  - Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`)
  - glog (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`)
  - react-native-camera (from `../node_modules/react-native-camera`)
  - react-native-fbsdk (from `../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk`)
  - react-native-google-places (from `../node_modules/react-native-google-places`)
  - react-native-keep-awake (from `../node_modules/react-native-keep-awake`)
  - react-native-onesignal (from `../node_modules/react-native-onesignal`)
  - react-native-splash-screen (from `../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen`)
  - react-native-video (from `../node_modules/react-native-video/react-native-video.podspec`)
  - React/Core (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/CxxBridge (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/DevSupport (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTActionSheet (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTAnimation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTGeolocation (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTImage (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTLinkingIOS (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTNetwork (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTPushNotification (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTSettings (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTText (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTVibration (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - React/RCTWebSocket (from `../node_modules/react-native`)
  - ReactNativeKeyboardManager (from `../node_modules/react-native-keyboard-manager`)
  - ReactNativeLocalization (from `../node_modules/react-native-localization`)
  - "RNCAsyncStorage (from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage`)"
  - RNDeviceInfo (from `../node_modules/react-native-device-info`)
  - RNGestureHandler (from `../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler`)
  - RNImageCropPicker (from `../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker`)
  - RNVectorIcons (from `../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons`)
  - yoga (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - Base64
    - boost-for-react-native
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - FBSDKShareKit
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleMaps
    - GooglePlaces
    - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform
    - GoogleUtilities
    - IQKeyboardManager
    - JWT
    - nanopb
    - OneSignal
    - PromisesObjC
    - QBImagePickerController
    - RSKImageCropper
    - SSZipArchive

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  CodePush:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-code-push"
  DoubleConversion:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  Folly:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
  glog:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  React:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native"
  react-native-camera:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-camera"
  react-native-fbsdk:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk"
  react-native-google-places:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-google-places"
  react-native-keep-awake:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-keep-awake"
  react-native-onesignal:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-onesignal"
  react-native-splash-screen:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen"
  react-native-video:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-video/react-native-video.podspec"
  ReactNativeKeyboardManager:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-keyboard-manager"
  ReactNativeLocalization:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-localization"
  RNCAsyncStorage:
    :path: "../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage"
  RNDeviceInfo:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-device-info"
  RNGestureHandler:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler"
  RNImageCropPicker:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker"
  RNVectorIcons:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons"
  yoga:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Base64: cecfb41a004124895a7bcee567a89bae5a89d49b
  boost-for-react-native: 39c7adb57c4e60d6c5479dd8623128eb5b3f0f2c
  CodePush: fe25db2e24ff1a2fab8b280a9633d9ba520867be
  DoubleConversion: bb338842f62ab1d708ceb63ec3d999f0f3d98ecd
  FBSDKCoreKit: 3e41c402eb64ea7799c71833ff9e5690f27b9c42
  FBSDKLoginKit: a88f36da648e4c5d60eb261c63eac067abb97130
  FBSDKShareKit: 8695bbb97c18a381bbf2851a3f24f95a59121b82
  Firebase: 8432d732974498afd5987e9001a05f90f1a3d625
  FirebaseAnalytics: 470ddab7253b21ad5a40bebd4a9903d7ae19386a
  FirebaseCore: 68f8a7f50cdae542715d4e86afa37c4067217dcb
  FirebaseInstanceID: ebd2ea79ee38db0cb5f5167b17a0d387e1cc7b6e
  Folly: de497beb10f102453a1afa9edbf8cf8a251890de
  glog: aefd1eb5dda2ab95ba0938556f34b98e2da3a60d
  Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK: 8b58584890539de4527c47ef01e4da941a10bc8a
  GoogleAppMeasurement: a35a645835bae31b6bdc0576396bc23908f12a22
  GoogleMaps: 5c13302e6fe6bb6e686b267196586b91cd594225
  GooglePlaces: e874db179f2675c4f3eeda0b686b540273a578b0
  GoogleUserMessagingPlatform: b168e8c46cd8f92aa3e34b584c4ca78a411ce367
  GoogleUtilities: 7f2f5a07f888cdb145101d6042bc4422f57e70b3
  IQKeyboardManager: 8eab4d8111418414619d1df8e4779ce5d0f8d7e2
  JWT: ef71dfb03e1f842081e64dc42eef0e164f35d251
  nanopb: 18003b5e52dab79db540fe93fe9579f399bd1ccd
  OneSignal: 0f5ff711d9f25da54885e4ab06ef0abc221a46ef
  PromisesObjC: 3113f7f76903778cf4a0586bd1ab89329a0b7b97
  QBImagePickerController: d54cf93db6decf26baf6ed3472f336ef35cae022
  React: a86b92f00edbe1873a63e4a212c29b7a7ad5224f
  react-native-camera: 37580137d13b0f2fabd631e4217eb11f0e4d5764
  react-native-fbsdk: bc1d3e321e8a710feaf8763d747707972d6c4299
  react-native-google-places: a667a22f22eaefec7aee140d842b43a898fa5b86
  react-native-keep-awake: 282a6c2d91e16907ddbe731e0fabdbdb56fd7b22
  react-native-onesignal: 4d16f59736eb92e892fb009cb66a7c508fdeead0
  react-native-splash-screen: 200d11d188e2e78cea3ad319964f6142b6384865
  react-native-video: 0871593feb37ae297a20943d77a142b30a1776b6
  ReactNativeKeyboardManager: ed6aeecadae8dff5404c446c5c16d7208290d348
  ReactNativeLocalization: 00800abad36a2a902b131c690d3e6143198ccc8a
  RNCAsyncStorage: 63407ea82f1b5ac8fc53a0b8c569b08e0516a9e0
  RNDeviceInfo: 5a3ae865d1736d2305be149578928b0c7198e852
  RNGestureHandler: 5329a942fce3d41c68b84c2c2276ce06a696d8b0
  RNImageCropPicker: 6134b66a3d5bc13e2895a97c630a4254006902b4
  RNVectorIcons: 0bb4def82230be1333ddaeee9fcba45f0b288ed4
  RSKImageCropper: 1ac71e9a82e3f41eea3eedfff8eacb0d3821c9ec
  SSZipArchive: e7b4f3d9e780c2acc1764cd88fbf2de28f26e5b2
  yoga: 03ff42a6f223fb88deeaed60249020d80c3091ee

PODFILE CHECKSUM: e6eea4e644e7083bd572c4e24e9cbdf6c1980f0a

COCOAPODS: 1.11.2
```